# Is there a phrase for "the first thing I want to see in the morning as I wake up"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a phrase for "the first thing I want to see in the morning as I wake up"?

Comment: There's one word actually: _coffee_.

Comment: How about "the first thing I want to see in the morning as I wake up"?

Comment: In malayalam we call it "kani"....seems to have no corresponding word in English

Comment: It used to be Loni Anderson, but that's been a few years.

Answer (score 3):

Without a sentence with context, I'd venture "rays of sunshine"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean "wishful thinking" or "hoping against hope"?

Comment: Not exactly....!!